# Split line layer by another line layer

Tags: qgis, postgresql, stream

I have two line layers . One is the stream network (dissolved) and other is the point layer converted to line layer by converting each point into short line segments. I am using "Split by lines" tool available by processing toolbox which splits the input line layer at the points where other line layer intersects .The resulting split layer has more splits and at locations other than the intersecting line layer points.

Is there any alternative for the tool or any update to the used approach to achieve the same.

Comment: Did u search in existing answers ?

Comment: Yes, none worked.

Comment: If u have two much 'splits' it is certainly because u didn't merge contiguous line features ... that means u didn't find the intersections as i told u before ...

Comment: The intersection points are re-checked and are absolutely fine.The merging is the logic to be implemented for degree two nodes , for which I dissolved the network and was expecting it to be re-splited by the tool.